# Cons of a liferay cms while website development using Community Edition

Tags: content-management-system, liferay

I am new to LIFERAY CMS. i need cons of a liferay cms i.e., difficulties faced while developing and using liferay cms.
can you please list cons of liferay cms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if this question really belongs here, anyway here are few my points:

- you have to get the proper Liferay mindset to get things work
- insufficient developer documentation (they are trying to improve it)
- a lot of code in JSP files
- little (if any) support for TDD
- many things are hard (or impossible) to override without hacking into the Liferay's source code

If you need just CMS, I would recommend looking for an other option, e.g. [Magnolia CMS](http://www.magnolia-cms.com) *(disclaimer: I am a former Magnolia CMS developer)*.

On the other hand, if you need a collaboration tool (wiki spaces, forums, possibility to create open/private groups, ...), then Liferay if probably the best free option (there are better, but paid).

Comment: I don't agree with the 
"many things are hard (or impossible) to override without hacking into the Liferay's source code" part. 

You can hook into so many parts of Liferay's core to modify internal behaviour, change views (jsps) and so on. Nevertheless, I do agree on the other points. Even though I wouldn't consider the lot of code in the jsp's a bad thing. This is the reason you can change things easily.

Comment: @Gevatterjan Hooks are nice, but see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976211/mapping-ldap-attribute-to-liferay-user-display-language/30997599 - mapping an additional LDAP attribute to an User property should be pretty basic task, but I had to dig the sources to find out, how exactly the LDAP import works (because it is not documented) and write an EXT plug-in (which is quite invasive). And there are other (IMHO fairly basic) things you cannot solve with hooks and use of an well-documented API.